# Unable to send Message to Mobile in Google app engine project

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working on Google App engine project .When I am Trying to send message from localhost:8888 it gives the following error in browser

There was a problem when attempting to send the message using the server at                 `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api`Is your API Key in MessageEndpoint.java (in your App Engine project) set correctly? Here's the error information:
com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401

I have set API key in MessageEndPoing.java and running local host.